# Tclsh convert base64 dump into zip file

Tags: zip, base64, tcl, 7zip

I have written a `Tclsh` code that will fetch a zip file content in base64 format through xml-rpc method. I am dumping that base64 data into a file using the following snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
...
set mybase64Dump [myXmlRpcCallToReturnThisDump]
set zipFilePtr [open "xyz.zip" "w"]
puts $zipFilePtr $mybase64Dump
close $zipFilePte
```

Zip file was getting generated with `XKbytes` of size, but when trying to open using `7zip` it says, `Is not Archive`. But I copy pasted the same base64 dump in a online converter. It was giving me a proper extractable zip file.

Is it something I am doing wrongly?

Comment: A zip file doesn't just contain the bytes of the file you want to store: it also has a lot of metadata that the unpacker needs to understand the content. The online converter probably created that metadata for you, but if you just store raw data in a file it won't be a zip archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to configure the output file to be binary, not ascii.  The default translation for a newly opened file is "auto", which does system-specific translation of the end-of-line characters, which is not what you want for a .zip file.  Configure this using fconfigure on the handle after opening it or by adding the BINARY access flag to the open command.

See http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm and http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm for details on the syntax.

Comment: Fun fact, the binary flag to open is _pure_ convenience. It just does an `fconfigure -translation binary` for you behind the scenes.